# Using Selenium to click on an element which is in nested <div> <li>

Tags: selenium-rc

My page looks like the code given below in inspect element mode.

I have series of li tags inside div tags, whose ids are dynamically created while I load the page.

I need to click on Summary, intent, conversion elements.

Can anyone please help me how to do this in selenium RC.

The ids are dynamically generated so I cannot use the id option here. For example : the id yui_3_3_0_1_131676060142810944 is dynamically generated. Using xpath also, I could not click on these elements.

Please let me know if there is a way out. It would be very helpful for me.

The actual inspected source is here if it might help in looking into this.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/696262/

Comment: Do you have any idea why you can't use xpaths? Or do you have some trouble getting your xpaths right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the DOM tree with nested div

```
<div class="aui-helper-clearfix aui-tree-node-content aui-tree-data-content aui-tree-node-    content aui-tree-node-selected aui-tree-expanded" id="aui_3_4_0_1_1005">
<div class="aui-tree-hitarea" id="aui_3_4_0_1_1224">
</div><div class="aui-tree-icon" id="aui_3_4_0_1_1214">
</div><div class="aui-tree-label aui-helper-unselectable" id="aui_3_4_0_1_1218">OSS</div>    </div>
```

Here is the xpath that selects the clickable node (for Selenium)

```
$x("//div[contains(@class,'aui-tree-node-content') and (contains(.,'OSS'))]//div[contains(@class,'aui-tree-hitarea')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is:

```
selenium.click("link=Summary");
...
selenium.click("link=Intent");
...
selenium.click("link=Conversion");
...
```

A little less obvious would be:

```
selenium.click("xpath=//*[@id='reports-subtab-summary']/a");
...
selenium.click("xpath=//*[@id='reports-subtab-intent']/a");
...
selenium.click("xpath=//*[@id='reports-subtab-conversions']/a");
...
```

which has the advantage that it doesn't depend on page-text that might change (due to language translation, *etc*.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use css path for example:

```
html body#gsr div#searchform.jhp form#tsf div.tsf-p div table tbody tr td table tbody tr td#sftab.lst-td div.lst-d table.lst-t tbody tr td table tbody tr td.gsib_a div input#lst-ib.gsfi
```